# Python venv - odoo17

Tags: python, odoo-17

```
danish@danish-dev:~/odoo17$ pyhton3.10 -m venv venv
Command 'pyhton3.10' not found, did you mean:
  command 'python3.10' from deb python3.10 (3.10.12-1~22.04.2)
Try: sudo apt install <deb name>
```

Creating a venv with python but its shows command not found

Comment: You probably need to use just python3 and not python3.10. If that doesn’t work check if python is installed on your OS.

Comment: it says like pyhton3 is already the newest version

Comment: Have you tried running python3 -m venv env?

Comment: danish@danish-dev:~/odoo17$ sudo apt install pyhton3.10-venv
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package pyhton3.10-venv
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'pyhton3.10-venv'